# How can I flag an answer not in English?

Tags: discussion, support, languages, english

I just hesitated flagging an answer in German to a question in English. I wasn't sure which flag option to choose, so I decided to send it to moderator attention with a note saying "This answer is in German."

Is this a right flag for this? What should I've done?

Comment: Very Low Quality may be suitable...

Comment: @Servy +1 Could serve well and may be better, because it doesn't involve asking for a mod's attraction.

Comment: Very Low Quality might have been better I think. I guess "Not An Answer" wouldn't work, because it **was** an answer actually.

Comment: @rene Ah, I couldn't find that. I have to search better.

Comment: @rene Yeah, close except that is for questions and not answers. You can't mark an answer as "unclear" or "off-topic"

Comment: @Kendra Apparently this is certainly a duplicate. Why can't I find these questions before asking? Anyway, thanks. And sorry for dupe everyone.

Comment: It's fine. Duplicates aren't a bad thing. SO search is known for being pretty bad, anyway. Most people use Google with a "site:" parameter added in.

Comment: With everyone fuming from their mouth when you flag crap answers as VLQ, I find the support to flag this as VLQ surprising. If there's anything salvageable, it's translating a perfectly good question from language X to English.