# Add Not in English flag for answer just as there is for question

Tags: feature-request, flags

There is a flag called "Not in English" for questions, but the same flag doesn't exist for answers.

I think it would be helpful if the same flag (called "Not in English") exists for answers so that users can choose it instead of flagging the answer for moderator review or as some other inaccurate flag. Currently, I flag the answers not written in English for moderator review as described at [How to flag an answer not in English?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286392/12002570)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it will be helpful to have this flag?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Like I come across many non-english written answers like [this most recent one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77698753/12002570) and I had to flag this for moderator review/attention saying "not in english". It would be better if we could have a separate flag called "not in english" for answers just like there already is for questions so that I don't have to flag it for moderator review or as not an answer etc. **Basically the same reason(s) we already have this flag for questions are also applicable here to answers.**

Comment: Not sure additional options are, ahem, an option. You'd have to replace something and the other options are significantly more likely to arise than a non-english answer. Priorities!

Comment: @Paulie_D That is an UI implementation detail/problem. Currently there are 7 options in the close menu for questions while only 5 in the close menu of answers. So it looks like there is plenty of space for this new flag.

Comment: The Not in English close reason was an easier thing to do because the site moderation team is able to manage our community close reasons. We don't need a staff member to implement anything to add a close reason. An answer flag would require an entirely new flag type as well as developer time to implement.

Comment: When requesting new flag types in the past we have been informed that implementing a new flag type is a significant undertaking and requires a non-trivial amount of development time. If this receives support, we can mark this as [status-review] to put it on staff RADAR and they'll make their decision from there based on available resources.

Comment: I believe [nukable discussions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427514/20153035) should come before not in english answer flags (we already have VLQ, which is what should be used for not in english answers)

Comment: @HenryEcker I don't know the inner workings of the SO infrastructure, but wouldn't that be a point one would want to streamline? (I know this is not exactly the point of this particular feature-request.) In my relatively short time on this site, a saw several discussions about changing/adding flags. Also, I would assume that flagging reasons may differ for the individual StackExchange sites.

Comment: @A-Tech the answer flag reasons are almost all the same across the network. There is a single flag which is not and can be opted in with, which is the first of its kind and [it was introduced in March this year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423749/plagiarism-flag-and-moderator-tooling-has-launched-to-stack-overflow). Sites can choose whether to enable it or not. Outside of that, sites in other languages can translate the text of the flags but there is no other "customisation" of flags available.

Comment: @HenryEcker That seems like an excuse for not wanting to have this flag(from user's POV).

Comment: @user12002570 I don't see any excuse. Just description of the reality we face. If there is enough support mods would move this to SE's internal tracker. But from then on it won't just magically happen. It's a company decision and it is possible to get delayed or rejected by them. Creating new flags take time and effort. It's just a fact. It's not a rebuttal against your feature request.

Comment: @VLAZ I think the *plan* is to allow other sites to opt into plagiarism flags, but currently it's only on SO. I don't believe that I've seen any announcements that the network level support has been completed (or even begun) to actually let sites opt into the flag.

Comment: @user12002570 Echoing VLAZ's points, I'm not making an excuse or trying to discourage the feature request. Personally, I think it would help because we really don't need more mod flags and these posts can easily be handled by LQA. I'm just letting you know what has been communicated to us about new flag types and the differences between site-specific close reasons (which are easily configurable without requiring system builds) and your request of a new dedicated flag.

Answer (score 12):

#### There is, currently, no need for a new "not in English" flag for answers.

##### Contrary to the statement in your question, there is no "Not in English" flag for questions.

There is a community specific **close reason** for "Not written in English", which was somewhat recently added. When a question is closed, there's a post notice showing specific information to the user as to why the post was closed and how the question author might edit their question in order for it to be reopened. There's definite benefit to telling users that they should edit their question to be in English using a dedicated **close reason**. It is possible for other users to either close-vote or raise a close-flag for the specific close reason of "Not written in English". However, unlike you have stated in your feature request here, it's not actually a "a flag called "Not in English" for questions". There is no such flag. There is a *close reason* and a flag for closure, which users with less than 3,000 reputation can raise. User's with more than 3,000 reputation can't raise close flags.

##### A Very Low Quality (VLQ) or Not An Answer (NAA) flag should be used for answers not in English, not an "in need of moderator intervention" flag.

You were using instructions contained in an antiquated answer. The correct instructions are in the [answer to the FAQ question: "How do I deal with non-English content?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/3773011). Those instructions are to use a VLQ flag, with NAA flags also being acceptable. An "in need of moderator intervention" flag that just states that the answer isn't in English is likely to be declined with the stock flag decline reason of:

> Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see [What is Flagging?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

Unfortunately, finding the correct instructions once you landed on [the question you were looking at](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286389/3773011) was complicated by there both being an inaccurate answer to that duplicate question and the duplicate targets on that question pointing to a confusing set of questions, including one that was merged into the actual [FAQ question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673/3773011) that holds the community maintained answer describing how such non-English content should be handled. I have deleted that inaccurate answer and adjusted the duplicate targets list for that question, and several other questions, to point directly to the FAQ "[How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673/3773011)".

##### Unlike a question close reason, there isn't any benefit to the answer author to having a separate "Not in English" flag.

Unlike question closure, there are no post notices telling users specifically why their answer was deleted. All such information is communicated through either a link to a general description of why answers might be deleted or contained in a custom comment on the answer. Thus, unlike closing a question for the "Not in English" reason, there would be no benefit to the answer author to having a specific "Not in English" flag.

While it would be possible to have a separate post notice for this answer deletion reason, it's a much larger ask to have that, because we then get into the issue of what other post notices should there be for answer deletion. That is something that could be/should be explored, but it requires quite a bit of work, including not just thinking about "what answer deletion post notices should there be", but also "how should it be determined what to use", etc. For example, would users in review queues need to specify a specific reason? Should > 20k users need to specify a specific reason when voting to delete? Should moderators need to specify a specific reason when voting to delete? How should it be handled when the reason selected is inaccurate? etc.

Comment: I don't think you really said anything different from me, but I quite like how you organized it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks. Yeah, it's largely similar to what you wrote. When I saw the notification of your answer being posted, I seriously considered deleting everything I'd already written and upvoting yours (which I did). If I hadn't already been largely finished writing this, I probably would have instead just posted a couple of comments explaining the duplicate-target issues with the other questions and that I deleted the inaccurate answer that's linked from the question. My going ahead and posting this was probably a manifestation of the "sunk-cost fallacy".

Comment: Great minds think alike, I guess.

Answer (score 10):

The reason we have a "Not in English" flag for questions is that it's a **closure reason**; users between 15 and 3000 reputation can flag a question as "Needs Improvement" and select one of these, rather than simply voting to close.

When a question is not written in English, we want to close it **so that people don't attempt to write answers** - even English answers written by a native English speaker who also understands the language of the question, are still not positively contributing to the site, because an English framing question is still required (among other things, the community can't be expected to properly assess whether the answer is accurate, or even topical).

When a question is not written in English, we **don't want to delete it immediately**, because it's entirely possible that OP can translate it. That's why Not in English is a closure reason, and not a separate flag outside the closure reasons.

Separating out a closure reason is useful because it helps explain to OP what is wrong with the question.

However, **an answer cannot be "closed"**, which is what makes all the difference. The only ways to take action on answer flags are to delete the answer or punish the author. In general, we would want to delete such answers, because "try to convince the author to translate it" is functionally equivalent to "no action", and "prevent replies" is moot.

Because such an answer will be deleted, and because **moderators are not expected to assess** whether the answer could be valid if translated, there is no point separating out a flag reason.

[Please flag answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673) that are not in English as "Very Low Quality"; "Not an Answer" also works.

Comment: one somewhat subtle benefit of VLQ flag over NAA in this case is that edit of the answer clear the VLQ flag so in case if poster properly translates it, VLQ flag gets cleared (resolved as helpful) and doesn't take any further efforts from anyone. Compared to that, NAA keeps hanging after such edits leading to situations when moderator handling at such flag may get confused why normally looking (English) answer has got NAA